# Using vue-underscore in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I’m currently reworking an application that I was making in VueJS for Nuxt, however I get an error missing stack frames that I can’t find much about – I’m trying to use `vue-underscore` and while previously in VueJS this worked fine, I’m now having this  missing stack frames error message appear.

In a `vue-underscore.js` file I setup underscore like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import underscore from 'vue-underscore'

Vue.use(underscore)
```

I import `{_}` like this in my component:

```
import {_} from 'vue-underscore';
```

Error message here:

```
"use strict";
    __webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
    /* harmony import */ var vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = 
    __webpack_require__(/*! vue */ "vue");
    /* harmony import */ var vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = 
    /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
    /* harmony import */ var vue_underscore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! vue-underscore */ "vue-underscore");
/* harmony import */ var vue_underscore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(vue_underscore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);
 vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.use(vue_underscore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a);
```

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: You will need to add it to 'plugins' in nuxt.config.js. like this:  `plugins: ['@/folderWhereYouSaved/vue-underscore.js']`

Comment: @Andrew1325 I have already done this unfortunately! Not the problem

Comment: I'm new to nuxt but I think that if you're doing a single page app mode, you gotta add ssr:false to your plugins like this in your nuxt.config.js: 

    plugins: [
     { src: '~/plugins/vue-underscore.js', ssr: false }
    ],

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. We both were badly using it!

Let's summarize.

1. Add the repo

`npm install vue-underscore`

OR

`yarn add vue-underscore`

2. Create a file named plugins/underscore.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import underscore from 'vue-underscore'
Vue.use(underscore)
```

3. Add it to the nuxtconfig.js file

`plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/underscore', ssr: false }]`

4. Use it

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$_.range(2000, 2020))
  }
}
</script>
```